# Cloud Formation Template design

Tags: aws-cloudformation

What factors do folk take into account when deciding to write 1 large CF template, or nest many smaller ones? The use case I have in mind is RDS based where I'll need to define RDS instances, VPC Security groups, parameter and option groups as well as execute some custom lambda resources.

My gut feel is that this should be split, perhaps by resource type, but I was wondering if there was generally accepted practice on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current rule of thumb is to split resources by deployment units - what deploys together, goes together.

I want to have the smallest deployable stack, because it's fast to deploy or fail if there's an issue. I don't follow this rule religiously. For example, I often group Lambdas together (even unrelated ones, depends on the size of the project), as they update only if the code/config changed and I tend to push small updates where only one Lambda changed.

I also often have a stack of shared resources that are used (`Fn::Import`-ed) throughout the other stacks like a KMS key, a shared S3 Bucket, etc.

Note that I have a CD process set up for every stack, hence the rule.

Comment: That's helpful thank you, particularly the commentary on deployment methiods vs shared resources.

Answer (score 2):

My current setup requires deployment of a VPC (with endpoints), RDS & application (API gateway, Lambdas). I have broken them down as

- VPC stack: a shared resource with 1 VPC per region with public & private subnets, VPC endpoints, S3 bucket, NAT gateways, ACLs, security groups.
- RDS stack: I can have multiple RDS clusters inside a VPC so made sense to keep it separate. Also, this is created after VPC as it needs VPC resources such as private subnets, security groups. This cluster is shared by multiple application stacks.
- Application stack: This deploys API gateway & Lambdas (basically a serverless application) with the above RDS cluster as the DB.

So, in general, I pretty much follow what @Milan Cermak described. But in my case, these deployments are done when needed (not part of CD) so *exported* parameters are stored in parameter store of `AWS Systems Manager`.

Comment: Storing exported params into Systems manager is also something I'm experimenting with. Cool to see other folks using this approach as well.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to systems manager. Probably not useful for my needs now, but definitely worth considering in the future.